# Ordering optional elements with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have some XML representing diferent items with three fields each (field1, field2, field3) and optionally two extra fields (field4, field5), like this:

```
<items>
    <data type="basic">
        <field1>A1</field1>
        <field2>A2</field2>
        <field3>A3</field3>
    </data>
    <data type="basic">
        <field1>B1</field1>
        <field2>B2</field2>
        <field3>B3</field3>
    </data>
    <data type="basic">
        <field1>C1</field1>
        <field2>C2</field2>
        <field3>C3</field3>
    </data>
    <data type="extra">
        <field4>C4</field4>
        <field5>C5</field5>
    </data>
    <data type="basic">
        <field1>D1</field1>
        <field2>D2</field2>
        <field3>D3</field3>
    </data>
    <data type="basic">
        <field1>E1</field1>
        <field2>E2</field2>
        <field3>E3</field3>
    </data>
    <data type="extra">
        <field4>E4</field4>
        <field5>E5</field5>
    </data>
</items>
```

I want to group them in a more orderly way, like this:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <field1>A1</field1>
        <field2>A2</field2>
        <field3>A3</field3>
    </item>
    <item>
        <field1>B1</field1>
        <field2>B2</field2>
        <field3>B3</field3>
    </item>
    <item>
        <field1>C1</field1>
        <field2>C2</field2>
        <field3>C3</field3>
        <field4>C4</field4>
        <field5>C5</field5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <field1>D1</field1>
        <field2>D2</field2>
        <field3>D3</field3>
    </item>
    <item>
        <field1>E1</field1>
        <field2>E2</field2>
        <field3>E3</field3>
        <field4>E4</field4>
        <field5>E5</field5>
    </item>
</items>
```

How can I do that with XSLT? I tried something like:

```
<items>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data[type='basic']"/>
</items>

<xsl:template match="data[type='basic']">
    <item>
        ...
    </item>
</xsl:template>
```

But I don't know how to match the corresponding 'extra' fields into the correct item element.

Comment: Will there only ever be one "extra" data element at most following a "basic" one?

Comment: Yes, only one at most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that `type` is an attribute, so you need to use the `@` prefix to denote this

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="data[@type='basic']"/>
```

Then, in your template matching the basic elements, you first to need to select the child nodes...

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

Then you need to select the first following `data` element, but only if it is an "extra"

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::data[1][@type='extra']" />
```

You would then have a template to match the "extra" one to output it's nodes

```
<xsl:template match="data[@type='extra']">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="items">
    <items>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="data[@type='basic']"/>
    </items>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data[@type='basic']">
    <item>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::data[1][@type='extra']" />
    </item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data[@type='extra']">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the Identity Template to copy all other nodes. (Replace this with `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` if you are using XSLT 3.0)

Also note, you could do `<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::data[1][@type='extra']/*" />`. Then you wouldn't need the template for the "extra" one.

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzR9

Comment: following-sibling::data[1][@type='extra']" will select the first element that has name 'data' and @type=extra, so when you're processing the data node that contains A1, your XPATH will select C4/C5.

Comment: That is not actually correct. `following-sibling::data[1]` will select the first `data` node that follows the current node, so doing `following-sibling::data[1][@type='extra']` will then only return that node if it is an "extra". The expression you are thinking of is `following-sibling::data[@type='extra'][1]`

Comment: You may be right. Can't check it today, but I seem to remember being tripped up because `following-sibling::data[1]` did not select the first data node. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: No worries. It can be confusing. Doing `following-sibling::data[1]` would only be an issue if there were nodes other than `data` in the XML, in which case it might have to be `following-sibling::*[self::data][1]`

Comment: This solution worked perfectly, thank you very much!
I had to adjust a few things because the real data was a bit more complicated than my example, but the secret was using "following-sibling", which I didn't know about before.